# Adding multiple tenants with Microsoft Partner Center

Tags: azure, entra-id

I am working to get two Azure tenants associated through the partner center. The two global admin accounts being used by the administrator do not have the same email address, but are both set to global admin permissions.

When the client signs into their Microsoft Partner Center, and goes into the Organization Info area in the Account Settings of the Microsoft Partner Center, they are not able to see the "Tenants" area that is available when I'm looking at my own tenant.

Based on the documentation on Microsoft, as long as you are signed in as the global admin you should be able to see this area on the Account Settings. When I have the customer sign into either of their tenants as their Global Admin, they are not able to see the Tenants area under Account Settings.

[Example of what I see in my Microsoft Partner Center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktX19.png)

[Example of what the customer sees in their Microsoft Partner Center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M999d.png)